# Javascript object with read only properties

Tags: javascript, object

In javascript, how to specify read only properties while using Object.create()?

Comment: Did you look at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) ? The example seems clear.

Comment: You configure property with descriptor `writable: false`.

Comment: Can you give me the syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Object.create()` method you can specify the `writable` property in the descriptor, which lets you choose either to make the property writable or not (read-only), here it is:

```
var myObject = Object.create(Object.prototype, {
    prop: {
        value: 123,
        writable: false
    }
});
```

Now you can try to re-write your property and you'll see that it stays unchanged:

```
console.log(myObject.prop); // 123

myObject.prop = 0;
console.log(myObject.prop); // 123
```

For more information about the `Object.create()` method see [**the MDN documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).